# PropertyChanged is null when calling thread from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, inotifypropertychanged, oxyplot

I have `MainWindow` class on which im showing realtime chart that is specified in `DataChart` class. Now when I run my app, chart will start adding new data and refreshing, because I start new thread for this in constructor of `DataChart` class. But what I need is to start updating chart AFTER I click button defined in `MainWindow` class, not after app start. But when I start same Thred from `MainWindow`, chart does not update and `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is null.

In `MainWindow`:

```
private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataChart chart = new DataChart();
            Thread thread = new Thread(chart.AddPoints);
            thread.Start();
        }
```

In `DataChart`:

```
public class DataChart : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DataChart()
        {
            DataPlot = new PlotModel();

            DataPlot.Series.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "1",
                Points = new List<IDataPoint>()
            });
            m_userInterfaceDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            //WHEN I START THREAD HERE IT WORKS AND PROPERTYCHANGED IS NOT NULL
            //var thread = new Thread(AddPoints);
            //thread.Start();                     
        }

        public void AddPoints()
        {
            var addPoints = true;
            while (addPoints)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_userInterfaceDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        (DataPlot.Series[0] as LineSeries).Points.Add(new DataPoint(xvalue,yvalue));
                        if (PropertyChanged != null) //=NULL WHEN CALLING FROM MainWindow
                        {
                            DataPlot.InvalidatePlot(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    addPoints = false;
                }
            }
        }
        public PlotModel DataPlot
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Dispatcher m_userInterfaceDispatcher;
    }
```

I think the problem why chart is not updating is that `PropertyChanged=null`, but i cant figure out how to solve it. Im using `OxyPlot` if it helps.

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<oxy:Plot Model="{Binding DataPlot}" Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: There is no code/XAML that causes any binding that would populate your PropertyChanged event.  What or who is "listening" to your property?

Comment: I don't see where you subscribed the `PropertyChanged` event? I believe you data bound it, but that should be different instance.

Comment: I have added MainWindow.xaml code.

Comment: What is MainWindow's DataContext?

Comment: How did the code look which you used during app start for setup/initialization of the DataChart? Since it worked then, as you said, seeing this code might give a hint about what is wrong and why some data binding is not working anymore...

Comment: I had `<local:DataChart/>` in `<Window.DataContext>` or in `<oxy:Plot.DataContext>`. Chart works the same in both cases.

Comment: During app start its two rows that i have put in comment `var thread = new Thread(AddPoints);` and `thread.Start();` . But when I start this thread from another class on button click it doesnt work (chart not updating).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are creating new instance of `DataChart` as local variable. How you you expect data binding would have subscribed its event?

DataBinding will have subscribed the event of instance which was set as the `DataContext`, so you need to call `AddPoints` on the same instance. Try the following:

```
private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataChart chart = (DataChart)this.DataContext;
    Thread thread = new Thread(chart.AddPoints);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: ´PropertyChanged´ in ´DataChart´ class has still null value (the chart not updating) when running thread, but ill try to work with this.